# How can I make my python window more presentable?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am studying python in high school so I am sorry if the answer to my problem seems obvious or that my code is sloppy.

I am using tkinter in python to make a window where the user puts what ingredients he has and when clicking on confirm, the window will show the recipes available to them inside a canvas. Here's what it currently looks like (apologies, the language is in French but it should be readable) [image: Screenshot of window]

Here's what my code looks like:

```
def takequantity():
 mondico["Tomate"] = saisirtomate.get()
 mondico["Fromage"] = saisirfromage.get()
 mondico["Farine"]= saisirfarine.get()
 #I copy and paste this as many times as I need for about 20 ingrediants

 if (mondico["Tomate"]>=5 and
     mondico["Farine"]>=500 and
     mondico["Fromage"]>=50):
    recette=can.create_text(300, 200, text="Pizza")
    #basically, if the ingrediants pass a certain threshold, it will recommend the Pizza recipe


mondico = {}
mondico["Tomate"] = 0
mondico["Farine"] = 0
mondico["Fromage"] = 0
#I copy and paste this as many times as I need for about 20 ingrediants
```

Below this, I have this:

```
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry("900x900")
window.minsize(height=900 ,  width=900)
window.config(background='#B8FAEF')


frame=tk.Frame(window, bg='#B8FAEF')

label_title = tk.Label(window, text="SmartFridgoo", font=("Comic Sans MS", 20))
label_title.pack()


label_subtitle = tk.Label(window, text="Veuillez entrez vos ingrédients", font=("Comic Sans MS", 10))
label_subtitle.pack()

frame.pack(expand=1)


Texttomate=tk.Label(window,text="Tomates",)
Texttomate.pack()
saisirtomate=tk.IntVar()
saisietomate=tk.Entry(textvariable=saisirtomate, width=9, justify='center')
saisietomate.pack()
#I copy and paste this, you get the idea

bouton=tk.Button(window,text="Confirmer et faire apparaître les recettes", command=takequantity)
bouton.pack()



can=tk.Canvas(window, bg='#B8FAEF', height=400, width=600)
can.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

What I would like is so that the slots where you put the numbers don't stack on top of each other and align like that. A grid formation would be nice, but I don't know how to do that.
I also would want to make it so the recipes appear at the center of the canvas but also that if multiple recipes are possible, I would want them to be neatly arranged and not on top of each other. How can I do that?

My apologies if I've done something wrong, it's my first post here.

EDIT: I would also like to be able to put a link attached to the text showing up. For example, when you would click on "Pizza" it would redirect you to a youtube recipe. I looked up how to do it with .bind but it doesn't work with texts from "can.create_text"

Comment: For positioning of the elements, [this site](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_layout_management.php) helped me.

Comment: do not use comic sans. ever.

Answer (score 0):

Grid formation is pretty easy in tkinter check [effbot.org](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) Cool thing is, you can use grid in your main window and also inside frames. For example you can create few frames and insert widgets inside with `widg.grid()`, and then place frames in window also using grid.